# spring bean default Priority

Tags: java, spring

In my simplified code sample I have 2 spring beans implementing the same interface (in real life the 2 components reside in different jars). One component (BeanImplBusiness in my sample) must be annotated with only `@Component`. The second one (BeanImplTest) can have any annotations.

The desired behavior is when both beans are in the classpath, spring to inject the "Business" bean in all places.

I try to achieve this using the `javax.annotation.Priority` annotation but it doesn't work the way I expect. Let me explain:

- put @Priority annotation only in "Test" component: spring will inject only the "Test" bean no matter what value I give to @Priority. It looks like the "Business" bean doesn't exists.
- put @Priority annotation in both beans and the lowest precedence in "Test" bean ( `@Priority(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)` ) it works perfectly, spring inject the "Business" component.

Spring version is 4.3.20, but I try also with 5.2.5 and I have same results.

So, my question is how can I configure the spring bean to give a default "Priority" on Business bean even if I don't declare it with annotation. Any solution with annotations, xml is good.

Why do I need to specify Priority annotations on both components? Is this a bug?

```java
import javax.annotation.Priority;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

public class SpringPriorityMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try (AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class)) {

            Bean bean = ctx.getBean(Bean.class);

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(bean.getName());
            System.out.println();

        }
    }

    public static interface Bean {

        String getName();
    }

    @Component
    // @Priority(0)
    public static class BeanImplBusiness implements Bean {

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "Business";
        }
    }

    @Component
    @Priority(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public static class BeanImplTest implements Bean {

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "Test";
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan("ro.catta.spring")
    public static class SpringConfig {

    }

}
```

The sample project is a maven project, here is the pom file to see exactly the dependencies

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ro.catta.poc</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-priority</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <mvn.spring.version>4.3.20.RELEASE</mvn.spring.version>
        <!-- <mvn.spring.version>5.2.5.RELEASE</mvn.spring.version> -->
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mvn.spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${mvn.spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${mvn.spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: If one bean has priority and one doesn't the one with it will always have higher priority and be chosen first. Priority is just the order the beans will be instantiated. If you want to autowire specific beans then use `@qualifier`.

Comment: @123 can you point a link to spring documentation for "If one bean has priority and one doesn't the one with it will always have higher priority and be chosen first."? The second suggestion using `@Qualifier` doesn't work because the injection point is not aware of differentiation between beans.

Comment: Nope, can't be bothered finding it either, that's how it works though. Also have no idea what your second statement is even meant to mean.